# How do I change the element the previews are added to in Dropzone

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have added Dropzone to my MVC project and have got uploads working great.
I'm initializing it with this code.

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {              
    init: function () {
        this.on("complete", function (data) {
            var res = JSON.parse(data.xhr.responseText);
            alert(data);
        });
    },
};
```

By default dropzone places all upload previews inside the form and I can't find any documentation on how to change this so that they are all placed in a div with a different id such as `#DropZonePreviews`. Been looking [here](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration) but I cant seem to find any attribute that would do this:

Any suggestions or am I missing something supereasy?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
    previewsContainer: "#DropZone-Preview",
    init: function () {
        this.on("complete", function (data) {
            var res = JSON.parse(data.xhr.responseText);
            alert(data);
        });
    },
};
```

Read through the source code and figured it out.. Above code puts the previews in a div with id `DropZone-Preview`